# How To Add A SyndicationElementExtension To A SyndicationItem

Tags: c#, .net, syndication, syndication-feed, atom-feed

Using the .NET System.ServiceModel.Syndication classes...

I would like to add a new SyndicationElementExtension to a SyndicationItem that will export the following XML:

```
<media:thumbnail url="http://www.foo.com/keyframe.jpg" width="75" height="50" time="12:05:01.123" />
```

Something along the lines of:

```
syndicationItem.ElementExtensions.Add(new SyndicationElementExtension("thumbnail", "http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss", ?
```

How do you create a simple SyndicationElementExtension with a few attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943475.aspx

> The
>   SyndicationElementExtensionCollection
>   class can also be used to create
>   element extensions from an XmlReader
>   instance. This allows for easy
>   integration with XML processing APIs
>   such as XElement as shown in the
>   following sample code.

```
feed.ElementExtensions.Add(new XElement("xElementExtension",
        new XElement("Key", new XAttribute("attr1", "someValue"), "Z"),
        new XElement("Value", new XAttribute("attr1", "someValue"), 
        "15")).CreateReader());
```

Answer (score 14):

Just to simplify for the next guy who comes along trying to figure this out, here's a working example of adding a basic item thumbnail (**RSS 2.0 enclosure** in this case) along the lines of the documentation:

```
SyndicationItem item = new SyndicationItem();

// populate item...

item.ElementExtensions.Add(
    new XElement( "enclosure",
        new XAttribute( "type", "image/jpeg" ),
        new XAttribute( "url", "http://path.to/my/image.jpg" )
    ).CreateReader()
);
```

You can also dump the attributes and just set textual content after the tag name if you want a simple tag, i.e. `<comments>http://my.comments/feed</comments>`.

Comment: how do you dump the attributes? If I don't pass any and also don't pass the namespace for an element, it inserts the attribute xmlns="" anyways.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing that happening at my end, the `xmlns=""` attribute is only specified on the outer `<rss></rss>` element. Can you post an example?