# ASPNET MVC: how do i add an image to a RSS item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rss, syndication-feed

I need to add an image to my RSS feed but cannot see it.

My code is:

```
var item = new SyndicationItem
(
    title: Title,
    content: Content,
    itemAlternateLink: new Uri(bla)
);
                    
item.ElementExtensions.Add(
    new XElement("enclosure",
        new XAttribute("type", "image/jpeg"),
        new XAttribute("url", new Uri(Uri))
    ).CreateReader()
);
```

If I use `ElementExtensions` I see a link to the image in the RSS but I would like to see directly the image without clicking the link. Is it possible?

Comment: have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1076964/576752

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to show an image in your RSS feed? If so, i believe that to show images in a feed you need the RSS media extensions - http://video.search.yahoo.com/mrss

For example, Zenfolio uses this to render photos in the gallery feeds.